# Cannot find user defined datatype 'empnum' in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014, temp-tables, user-defined-types

When I run the following query in SQL Server 2014 to create a temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp 
(   
    location char(16) null, 
    location_desc varchar(25) null, 
    Emp_Num EMPNUM null
)
```

I receive the error:

> Cannot find the data type empnum.

`empnum` is a user-defined data type.  But the same user-defined data type is working fine in other stored procedures.

Why am I receiving this error?

Comment: Can you show us the offending query?

Comment: CREATE TABLE #temp                                                                      
 (                                                                 
 location   char(16) null,                                                         
 location_desc varchar(25) null,                                                                     
 Emp_Num    EMPNUM   null,                                                            
}

Answer (score 3):

If using the tempdb, you need to define the type in the `model` database since types are at the db level. If the type has been defined for the `model` then you may still have permissions issues if the `model` db hasn't been given the `db_ddladmin` role.

The `model` db is a template for all new db's, `tempdb` does not persist between restarts, it is created new each startup.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [user defined types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx) are defined at `database level`, not `instance level`, so they must be defined for each database. For `temporary tables`, that means `tempdb` - creation query should be something like the following:

```
exec tempdb.sys.sp_executesql N'CREATE type EMPNUM ...';
```

A discussion regarding this subject can be found [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/421108/cant-use-an-alias-type-user-defined-data-type-when-creating-a-temp-table).

Comment: Thanks Alexei, your comment helped solve my problem!