# Cannot find data type user defined data type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting `Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type dbo.SUBSYSTEM_CODE.` error on user datatype.

```
    CREATE TABLE #PREDEFINED_SUBSYSTEMS
    (
        SUBSYSTEM_CODE      dbo.SUBSYSTEM_CODE PRIMARY KEY
    );
```

After I checked user defined datatype I can see. I am using SQL 2012 and also I applied `set compatibility_level = 110` on datatype still didn't work.

What other alternatives I have to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find user defined datatype 'empnum' in SQL Server 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36003051/cannot-find-user-defined-datatype-empnum-in-sql-server-2014)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to define type inside `tempdb`:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TYPE dbo.SUBSYSTEM_CODE ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Our problem was with schema

we moved table type from dbo to hub schema, and after that we got this error,

you need to use schema before table name for it to work

and dont forget about dynamic sqls which you might have